# Sparql howto select one result to ask another service in federated search

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, virtuoso, federated-queries

How I can select one of rdf possible labels to send it to the Federated Search?

I have a rdf record who has several links to another databases:

```
<owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://cantic.bnc.cat/registres/CUCId/a10035400"/>
<owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://viaf.org/viaf/61502721"/>
<owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Delfi_Abella"/>
<owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://id.loc.gov/authorities/names/nr2005020137"/>
<owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://d-nb.info/gnd/158288475"/>
```

I just get the dbpedia link to ask in dbpedia some information using It.

I create this federated search but It not works:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl/>
PREFIX rdaGr2: <http://rdvocab.info/ElementsGr2/>
PREFIX dbo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?autid rdaGr2:dateOfBirth "1991" .
  ?autid owl:sameAs ?dbpediaid 
  FILTER regex(?dbpediaid,'dbpedia','i') .
  SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>
  {
    ?dbpediaid dbo:birthPlace ?naixement
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

If I use the single search:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl/>
PREFIX rdaGr2: <http://rdvocab.info/ElementsGr2/>
PREFIX dbo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?autid rdaGr2:dateOfBirth "1991" .
  ?autid owl:sameAs ?dbpediaid 
  FILTER regex(?dbpediaid,'dbpedia','i') .
}
```

I get the autid and the dbpedia link.

```
autid                                                           dbpediaid
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a10985256/  http://dbpedia.org/resource/Emma_Roberts
```

How I can tell to the SERVIE just use It.

Regards

---

### Update (originally posted as an answer)

Maybe I'm asking badly the question:

I try to do two different sparql in just one. Using the results from the first part of question (Filter aplied) i try to ask into DBPEDIA to get the results I need.

From the first part without any Filter

```
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX void: <http://rdfs.org/ns/void#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl/>
PREFIX rdaGr2: <http://rdvocab.info/ElementsGr2/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?autid rdaGr2:dateOfBirth "1991" .
  ?autid owl:sameAs ?dbpediaid 
 }
```

I get this results:

```
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a10603050/  http://cantic.bnc.cat/registres/CUCId/a10603050
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a10603050/  http://viaf.org/viaf/169463957
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a10667283/  http://cantic.bnc.cat/registres/CUCId/a10667283
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a10667283/  http://viaf.org/viaf/303916880
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a10895814/  http://cantic.bnc.cat/registres/CUCId/a10895814
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a10895814/  http://viaf.org/viaf/107201286
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a10895814/  http://d-nb.info/gnd/140511695
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a10895814/  http://id.loc.gov/authorities/names/no2010103795
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a10985256/  http://cantic.bnc.cat/registres/CUCId/a10985256
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a10985256/  http://viaf.org/viaf/85925873
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a10985256/  http://id.loc.gov/authorities/names/no2005021393
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a10985256/  http://d-nb.info/gnd/141167203
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a10985256/  http://dbpedia.org/resource/Emma_Roberts
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a11019682/  http://cantic.bnc.cat/registres/CUCId/a11019682
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a11019682/  http://viaf.org/viaf/157747131
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a11045553/  http://cantic.bnc.cat/registres/CUCId/a11045553
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a11045553/  http://viaf.org/viaf/126161085
```

I apply the filter

```
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX void: <http://rdfs.org/ns/void#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl/>
PREFIX rdaGr2: <http://rdvocab.info/ElementsGr2/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?autid rdaGr2:dateOfBirth "1991" .
  ?autid owl:sameAs ?dbpediaid 
  FILTER regex(?dbpediaid,'dbpedia','i') .
}
```

to jut get one result:

```
http://arties.cbuc.cat/openccuc/a10985256/  http://dbpedia.org/resource/Emma_Roberts
```

And I want to send It to the Service to the DBPEDIA but just send this URL:
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Emma_Roberts

Not all the URL I  get from the first part:

```
http://cantic.bnc.cat/registres/CUCId/a10603050
http://viaf.org/viaf/169463957
http://cantic.bnc.cat/registres/CUCId/a10667283
http://viaf.org/viaf/303916880
http://cantic.bnc.cat/registres/CUCId/a10895814
http://viaf.org/viaf/107201286
http://d-nb.info/gnd/140511695
http://id.loc.gov/authorities/names/no2010103795
http://cantic.bnc.cat/registres/CUCId/a10985256
http://viaf.org/viaf/85925873
http://id.loc.gov/authorities/names/no2005021393
http://d-nb.info/gnd/141167203
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Emma_Roberts
```

Because some of them are not related to the Dbpedia and then the DBPEDIA send me an error like this:

```
Virtuoso RDFZZ Error DB.DBA.SPARQL_REXEC('http://dbpedia.org/sparql', ...) returned Content-Type 'text/plain' status 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
'
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 3: syntax error at '_' before ':'

SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0  SELECT ?naixement
 WHERE  {  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Emma_Roberts> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace> ?naixement .
     FILTER (_::default-20-7 =  <http://arties.cbuc.es:8990/CCUCAF>) }

SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
define sql:signal-void-variables 1 define get:soft "soft" define input:default-graph-uri <http://arties.cbuc.es:8990/CCUCAF> PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX void: <http://rdfs.org/ns/void#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl/>
PREFIX rdaGr2: <http://rdvocab.info/ElementsGr2/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?naixement
WHERE {
  ?autid rdaGr2:dateOfBirth "1991" .
  ?autid owl:sameAs ?dbpediaid 
  filter regex( str(?dbpediaid),'dbpedia','i')

  SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>
  {
    ?dbpediaid dbo:birthPlace ?naixement
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**FILTER regex(?dbpediaid,'dbpedia','i')** should probably fail, since ?dbpediaid isn't a string;  but a URI.  Instead, you should be doing **FILTER regex(str(?dbpediaid),'dbpedia','i')**.  The fact that your second query returns some results, though, makes it seem like the URI is implicitly being converted to a string.  That might be an extension of the particular implementation you're using, though.

However, when I use Apache Jena to execute the following query, I get empty results:

```
prefix dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select * where {
  bind( dbpedia:Emma_Roberts as ?dbpediaid )
  filter regex( ?dbpediaid,'dbpedia','i')

  service <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
    ?dbpediaid dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?naixement
  }
}
```

```
-------------------------
| dbpediaid | naixement |
=========================
-------------------------
```

If I make the change to using **str(?dbpediaid)**, I get results:

```
prefix dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select * where {
  bind( dbpedia:Emma_Roberts as ?dbpediaid )
  filter regex( str(?dbpediaid),'dbpedia','i')

  service <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
    ?dbpediaid dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?naixement
  }
}
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| dbpediaid            | naixement                                                   |
======================================================================================
| dbpedia:Emma_Roberts | <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rhinebeck_(village),_New_York> |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that this could be a very expensive query if the query engine does the **service** part first, as it would retrieve *all* the dbpedia-owl:birthPlace triples first, bring them back, and *then* match against the particular one that you care about.  There may be different behavior if rather than using **bind**, like I did above, the value of ?dbpediaid is simply coming from some triple matches.

Comment: Sorry but maybe I'm explain badly

Comment: @jordiPallares You posted an "answer" that isn't actually an answer, and should have been an edit to the question. I think I understand what you're trying to do:  you're trying to query data from one place (not DBpedia) and then use *some* of those values as parameters in a query to DBpedia that's performed by `service <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> { … }`.  Is that correct? You then said that **Because some of them are not related to the Dbpedia and then the DBPEDIA send me an error like this: …**. The error message doesn't say that the problem is that the URIs "are not related to DBpedia", but…

Comment: …rather that DBpedia is returning text instead of SPARQL results.  The actual text that it's returning is the error message from DBpedia: **Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 3: syntax error at '_' before ':'** referring, I presume, to the line of the query: `FILTER (_::default-20-7 =  <http://arties.cbuc.es:8990/CCUCAF>)`.  I expect that it's complaining about `_::default-20-7`, but I'm not sure.  If you got such a detailed error message, then you should have posted it in the  original question.

Comment: You **did** get a more detailed error than what you put in your original question. You posted it in an answer; that's where i copied it from!